# Android Studio Google Drive AppFolder Backup and Restore (Databases files)

Tags: android, database, android-studio, database-backups, google-drive-android-api

Hey I was follow QuickStart of Google Drive at the github:

https://github.com/gsuitedevs/android-samples/blob/master/drive/demos/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo/CreateFileInAppFolderActivity.java

I used SCOPE_APPFOLDER, So when i run the app, It asked me to login to google account and give access to open App Folder, after i am accept i go to google drive and yes it's open a folder for my app at the "App manger" (1KB).
[image]

My question is:
1) How can I upload database file (I have the path of it) to Google Drive AppFolder?
2)How can I download those databases files that i will upload from AppFolder and put them inside the path that i want?

I was write some code that make backup to those databases files **BUT** inside the device and it's look like this:

```
    //Back Up 
private void BackUp() {
    try {
        final String inFileName = "/data/user/0/com******/databases/**********";
        File dbFile = new File(inFileName);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(dbFile);
        String outFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/********";

        // Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        // Transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        // Close the streams
        output.flush();
        output.close();
        fis.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

How can i use some thing like the above code to google drive AppFolder????

Below is the code that i use for Google Drive Stufe

```
//Path of the file
 final String inFileName = "/data/user/0/com.******/databases/Categor****";
 File dbFile = new File(inFileName);
```

And i use this to create AppFolder:

```
    private void createFileInAppFolder() {
    final Task<DriveFolder> appFolderTask = getDriveResourceClient().getAppFolder();
    final Task<DriveContents> createContentsTask = getDriveResourceClient().createContents();
    Tasks.whenAll(appFolderTask, createContentsTask)
            .continueWithTask(task -> {
                DriveFolder parent = appFolderTask.getResult();
                DriveContents contents = createContentsTask.getResult();
                OutputStream outputStream = contents.getOutputStream();
                try (Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream)) {
                    writer.write("Hello World!");
                }

                MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                        .setTitle("New file")
                        .setMimeType("text/plain")
                        .setStarred(true)
                        .build();
                final String inFileName = "/data/user/0/com.camel.work_list/databases/CategoriesSpinner";
                File dbFile = new File(inFileName);
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(dbFile);

                MetadataChangeSet test = new MetadataChangeSet(fis);

                return getDriveResourceClient().createFile(parent, changeSet, contents);
            })
            .addOnSuccessListener(this,
                    driveFile -> {
                        showMessage(getString(R.string.file_created));
                        //finish();
                    })
            .addOnFailureListener(this, e -> {
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to create file", e);
                showMessage(getString(R.string.file_create_error));
                //finish();
            });
}
```

So i understand from this code that when it open a AppFolder it's create some text file with "Hello World"

How can i take my file from databases and upload to this AppFolder? and How can i Download/Restore this files and put them back to app folder inside the device?

Thank you guys :)

Comment: Can you reach a solution? I have the same problems.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Working with the Application Data folder**

> The application specific folder is accessible using the alias
>   appDataFolder. This alias can be used like any other folder ID; for
>   instance, when listing the files located directly under your
>   application's folder or when creating files by using appDataFolder as
>   the parent.

**Inserting a file into the Application Data folder**

```
File fileMetadata = new File();
fileMetadata.setName("config.json");
fileMetadata.setParents(Collections.singletonList("appDataFolder"));
java.io.File filePath = new java.io.File("files/config.json");
FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("application/json", filePath);
File file = driveService.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent)
    .setFields("id")
    .execute();
System.out.println("File ID: " + file.getId());
```

2. **Follow the** [Download Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads)

   - Download a file — files.get with alt=media file resource
   - Download and export a Google Doc — files.export
   - Link a user to a file — webContentLink from the file resource

Comment: @sharon2469 Android Studio is telling you it doesn't know how to handle the FileContent class. Here is information on the class you'll need to import: (https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/reference/1.19.0/com/google/api/client/http/FileContent)

Answer (score 1):

Refer this official documentation for backing up files in Google Drive's private "App data" folder.
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/appdata

Snippet from the link :

**Create a file in the application data folder**

```
File fileMetadata = new File();
fileMetadata.setName("config.json");
fileMetadata.setParents(Collections.singletonList("appDataFolder"));
java.io.File filePath = new java.io.File("files/config.json");
FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("application/json", filePath);
File file = driveService.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent)
    .setFields("id")
    .execute();
System.out.println("File ID: " + file.getId());
```

**Search for files in the application data folder**

```
FileList files = driveService.files().list()
    .setSpaces("appDataFolder")
    .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)")
    .setPageSize(10)
    .execute();
for (File file : files.getFiles()) {
  System.out.printf("Found file: %s (%s)\n",
      file.getName(), file.getId());
}
```

Use **DriverServiceHelper** class from [this link](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/android-samples/tree/master/drive/deprecation/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/driveapimigration)